# Retrieving information from Instagram using an unauthenticated request?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I'm attempting to use the Instagram with Python and I'm running into an issue just using the stock examples on their [GitHub page.](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) I'm following the steps exactly in the first unauthenticated request section, and I'm being thrown the following errors.

My code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "..."
client_secret = "..."
client_id = "..."
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
for media in popular_media:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 189, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 131, in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.', status_code=response['status'])
instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

Any help would be appreciated! Again, this code is just straight from the docs so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: You're getting a (404 - Not Found), the github repo may be using outdated urls

Answer (score 0):

According to the Instagram Developers page,

"**Instagram Platform and documentation update**. Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors."

As a result, if you created your app before Nov 17, 2015, you will not be able to perform unauthenticated requests.

Those docs from the python-instagram page(Last updated over 9 months ago) are outdated if your app was created before Nov 17, 2015.